# Date formatter produces inconsistent results

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want to show formatted date instead of timestamp. My code:

```
private static final String CRAWLER_DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
protected static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(CRAWLER_DATE_FORMAT);
```

This log line is called in every 3 seconds:

```
LOG.error("Timestamp: " + timestampString + " Formatted Date: " + DATE_FORMAT.format(Long.parseLong(timestampString));
```

My LOG:

```
Timestamp: 1491078405854 Formatted Date: 16-04-2017 21:25:20 <==
Timestamp: 1491078405854 Formatted Date: 01-04-2017 23:26:45
Timestamp: 1491078405854 Formatted Date: 01-04-2017 23:26:45
Timestamp: 1491078405854 Formatted Date: 01-04-2017 23:26:45
Timestamp: 1491078405854 Formatted Date: 01-04-2017 23:26:45
Timestamp: 1491078405854 Formatted Date: 16-04-2017 21:25:20 <==
Timestamp: 1491078405854 Formatted Date: 01-04-2017 23:26:45
```

Why do I get different results?

Comment: I think reason is thread execution. This may stop an execution for some reason. it will be executed.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe

Comment: Thanks. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( yourLongNumber );
       .toString()
```

## Details

The old date-time classes have, amongst their many flaws, a lack of thread-safety.

Use the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome legacy classes. The java.time classes use immutable objects and are thread-safe.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( yourLongNumber );
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2017-01-23T12:34:56.789Z

If you do not like the T either call `String::replace` or use a `DateTimeFormatter`. Both are shown in many other Questions and Answers on Stack Overflow.

For flexibility in formatting, convert the basic `Instant` into an `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss" , Locale.US );
String output = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).format( f );
```

Whenever possible, I suggest sticking with the standard ISO 8601 formats used by default in the java.time classes. The standard formats are quite appropriate to logging, which seems to be the domain of your Question.

Your desired format is ill-advised as it lacks an indication of offset or zone. That lacking may lead people to make incorrect assumptions about the offset/zone and misinterpret what they are reading. So I strongly recommend always including the offset/zone info. I also recommend doing all your logging in UTC. Both programmers and admins should learn to think of UTC as the One True Time.

Comment: How to set formatter with this way as "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" ?

Comment: Your `SimpleDateFormat` would have given you a time in the computer’s time zone. If you want the same, use `instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())`. In this case, allow me to suggest you also include the time zone offset in the log output so no one reading the log can be in doubt, for instance using `"dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss Z'['VV']'"` (this produces something like `01-04-2017 22:26:45 +0200[Europe/Oslo]`).

Comment: @OleV.V. Did you intend your Comment for the Question rather than my Answer?

Comment: @BasilBourque, the “you” in my comment is the asker (or I would have tagged you), but my intention was my idea could be used together with your answer, so in that sense it was a comment or supplement to the answer. Sorry it was unclear, so thanks for asking.